# Cannot import RMMapView

Tags: ios, dictionary, openstreetmap

I downloaded route-me library to use Openstreetmap in iPhone. I followed the instruction of the github and goggle code but my xcode5 cannot recognise it.

My project settings are like below:

[image: I imported the library as sub-project]

[image: Library directory location]

[image: I added header search path in project setting]

Header search path

```
$(inherited)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
../route-me-master/MapView
```

What do I need to fix?

Comment: Can you access the path `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
../route-me-master/` in finder?

Comment: The directories exist in my system and I can find them in finder.

Comment: Do the examples work for you?  
As this is a very specific question and the OSM dev community is smal here and spread over a lot of frameworks, you might consider to use the official support channels: https://github.com/route-me/route-me